# Unsupervised learning dimensionality reduction with scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to do dimensionality reduction/PCA on this 4-dimensional data.

```
test = [[[[3,10],[1,5],[3,18]],[[3,1],[0,0],[0,0]],[[3,3],[1,5],[0,0]]],[[[1,5],[2,7],[0,0]],[[1,7],[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]]]

from sklearn import decomposition
pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(test)
```

I am using `sklearn.decomposition.PCA`, but it gives me the following error:

"Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2."

Any pointers to why the error is occurring? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See the [documentation of PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.fit). It required 2 d array (n_samples, n_features). Your data is 4d

Comment: Can you explain about the data?

Comment: Essentially, I am trying to do clustering with scikit-learn algorithms. I thought PCA would be a good way to reduce the data from 4 dimensions to 2 dimensions. What can I use in Python to do unsupervised clustering on this kind of data? I get the same error, "Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2", when using `sklearn.mixture.GMM().fit()`.

Comment: Your data is not interpretable without any further explanation. Format it in a way such as n datapoints described by m dimensions - a n * m matrix. Then everything works fine